# pass data from child component to parent component Angular4

Tags: angular, components

I have lists of apis which are stored in a server: `ServerGetData`, like this:

```
apis = {
 "Repo Assignment": "https://apis.repoAssignment",
 "Status Summary": "https://apis.statsSummary",
 ...
}
```

I have created a child component drop down menu: `TitleDropdownComponent` child component, which displays all api titles: "Repo Assignment"...

In my parent component, I wanted to render different data tables based on the title which is selected from child component.

Right now, I can successfully get titles from child component and print them in the console in parent component, However, in my `ngOnInit()`, the same variable can not be changed accordingly, always get same api data because of title variable does not change.

How can I change the title variable in `ngOnInit` or using other way like `ngOnChanges`?

Please see my parent app component below.

```
import { Component, Input, EventEmitter, Output, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerGetData } from './server.getData';
import { TitleDropdownComponent } from './TitleDropdown/titleDropdown.component'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  // make ajax call from ServerGetData

  constructor(private dataService: ServerGetData) {}

  data = {};

  // get Child component variables

  @ViewChild(TitleDropdownComponent)
  private titleComponent: TitleDropdownComponent;
  
  onSelected(selected: string) {
    // default child component title is "Repo Assignment", in here overwrite 
    // titleComponent.title to be selected title
    this.titleComponent.title = selected;
    // each time can the selected title can be printed in console
    console.log(this.titleComponent.title);
    return this.titleComponent.title;
  }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.dataService.getData(this.titleComponent.title).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.data = data.items;
      }
    );
  };

}
```

I have no idea why here `this.titleComponent.title` is not able to change accordingly and always is default title: "Repo Assignment".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ngOnInit` is only always executed one time when the component is initialized. It won't later re-execute as other selections are made.

If you need to reget the data each time a new item is selected, move the code to within the onSelected method.

```
  onSelected(selected: string) {
    // default child component title is "Repo Assignment", in here overwrite 
    // titleComponent.title to be selected title
    this.titleComponent.title = selected;
    // each time can the selected title can be printed in console
    console.log(this.titleComponent.title);

    this.dataService.getData(this.titleComponent.title).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.data = data.items;
      }
    );

    return this.titleComponent.title;
  }
```

Comment: Hi @DeborahK, thank you so much! it works. However, I found the the data cannot be overwritten, meaning the the data I got is both from ngOninit and onSelected. Is any way, I only need onOnInit run one time after that, the data source will be from onSelected() ?

Comment: thank you! I think I figured it out. I just changed the order of onSelected() below the ngOnInit().